# Get <table> element from external page as htmltext

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get  element from an external page as **plaintext** using Simple Html Dom.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

include('simple_html_dom.php');  
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.vedora.sk/obchodnici/index.php');

$myContent = $html->find('table')->plaintext;
echo $myContent;

$html->clear();  
    unset($html);  
?>
```

There is only one . If I run the code, I get error:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/tmp.php on line 12

EDIT: is there any way to get  as html (as is)?

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: Also, what's line 12? Developers are lazy. If we have to count, we're not going to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure `$html->find('table')` returns an array of elements, even if there is only one. If you only want to find one element, you'd use `$html->find('table', 0)` (0 meaning index 0).

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem, but is there any way to get <table> as html (as is)?

Comment: No idea what you're asking for. Maybe use `outertext` instead? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Comment: Get and write out complete table from <table> to </table>, not plaintext content.

Comment: Don't use the `plaintext` property then. Use one of the others, such as `outertext`. Might want to review the API documentation so you know how it works.